# How to run sequential queries(which are interdependent) in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I've a set of queries to be ran in order to pass the data to a base query. How to achieve this in SOAPUI using groovy?

For instance, Query1 is the base query and queries Query2 and Query3 and so on are sub queries... So firstly I need to run Query3 and pass the data to Query2 and run the Query2 to pass the values to base query i.e. Query1.

Comment: Would you quote a sample of your query which you are talking about as that make life easier for other to understand better? By the way, have you seen JDBC test step? If so, what is the issue there. Would it be possible to show it with a screen shot of the error?

Comment: @rao I'm a newbie to SOAPUI and especially for JDBC queries using Groovy. So i haven't started working yet on this part as I wanted to check for the suggestions..

Comment: Hi, your question doesn't offer too much to go on.  In general terms, Rao's suggestion is a good one.  The JDBC step is perfect for this.  You can also achieve the above just using Groovy scripts.  Also, and this isn't clear from your question, if you're queries are not part of a wider test that includes calls to an API, you could simply use any programming language, such as Java, Javascript, C#, Python etc. to create your test, instead of using SoapUI.